# Array Results in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, html-table

Is it possible to limit the results shown from a MYSQL database?

At the moment the results are shown in a html table, how do I only show the newest entries?

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","cl49-XXX","XXX");
if (!$con) 
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("cl49-XXX", $con)or die("Unable to select database");

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products") or die('You need enter a category');

echo "<tr>"; // first row beginning
for ($i = 1; $i <= mysql_num_rows($result); $i++)
{
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

  $prodname = $row['prodname'];
  $prodID = $row['prodID'];
  $catagory = $row['catagory'];

  echo "
  <td>$prodID</td>
  <td>$prodname</td>
  <td>$catagory</td>
  <td>
    <a href=deleteproduct.php?q=$prodID' class='btn mini red'>
    <i class='icon-trash'></i> Delete Item</a>
  </td>";

  echo "</tr><tr>"; // it's time no move to next row
}
echo "</tr>"; // last row ending
?>
```

Comment: have you considered using LIMIT and possibly ORDER BY clauses in your MySQL query ?

Comment: Can you define "newest"? Are you storing a timestamp or have an auto-increment id?

Comment: This will give you 10 latest products for example: $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products order by ProdID desc limit 10")

Comment: Also your echo "<tr>" and echo "</tr>" statements should be outside the for loop unless you want to display all results in a single table row.

Comment: put your first sentence in Google and you would've already had your answer....

Answer (score 1):

Just switch your query to something like this!

```
 $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products LIMIT 0,10")or die('You need enter a catagory' );
```

LIMIT 0,10 will show the first 10 results from your DB.

You could even order it by a specific element in your DB.

```
 $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY objectName LIMIT 0,10")or die('You need enter a catagory' );
```

For further SQL basic help: http://www.sqlcommands.net/

Good luck!

Comment: What is your code? Replace objectName for what row you want to order your product by.

Answer (score 1):

Your question Consists of two parts.

**First part:** `Is it possible to limit the results shown from a MYSQL database?`

you can do that by using `limit`word inside the query.

Example:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products limit 1, 5");
```

The previous code say select all products and start from the product one and show me 5 products only.

**Second part:** `how do I only show the newest entries ?`

You can do that by, must first create column called `date` to your products table, then when add new product, store the time by using `time()` function into `date` column.
Then when you want to show the products order by newest products, you can use `order by` sentence.

Example:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products order by date ASC limit 1, 5");
```

**To apply these words on your code, only need to**

1. Add new column in your products table and call it `date`.
2. Then change the query that adds the products to products table to add also
   the time to the date column by using time() function.
   `INSERT INTO tableName(date) VALUES('".time()."');`
3. Show the products sorted order by newest by modify the query to

   `$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 0, 15") or die('You need enter a category');`

Comment: Thanks thats great, could you please inform me how i add the date? Im not sure?

Comment: You can Add the date/time by using [time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function, for example: `INSERT INTO tableName(date) VALUES('".time()."');`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, while you're still new, you should look into PDO/Prepared statements instead of mysql_ functions.

Also, you can do this for your SQL:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 0,10")or die('You need enter a catagory ' );
```

'name' being the name of your products/row name you wish to sort it by

Comment: I would love to experiment on a website's database structure with unsecured `mysql` PHP queries :)

Comment: Change 'name' for what row you want to order your product by.

Answer (score 0):

just add a counter and when the counter hits a number use:

```
break;
```

to jump out the loop.

for example

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= mysql_num_rows($result); $i++)
{
 if ($i==3) break;
}
```

Of course you could better limit the loop itself:

use:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++)
```

or use the LIMIT option in the SQL-query